# 0 questions posted on MSE - bug

Tags: bug

I'm not sure how / why this happened, but my main screen showed no questions, and even "0 questions posted on MSE" (see image below).

I can access past questions (like answer I wrote), but do not get to see new ones.

[image]

Comment: Same here, but it got sorted out after a couple of minutes.

Comment: Mine got sorted out, and then unsorted out.

Comment: It was also happening at MO. Glad it is not my computer having a tantrum.

Comment: It's not a bug, the site was deleted because it promotes Cantorian set theory and other lies! ;-)

Comment: It happens from time to time.